# D3 Js Vertical Line Intersection with Horizontal Threshold Line

Tags: d3.js, search, graph

I m working on a topic modelling project and have some d3js date/distribution graphs for visualization. I need to draw some vertical lines which touches with horizontal threshold lines (red lines). According to that i will measure date distance and look for anomalies etc..

Following graph is what i want , but i could not find the points where it touches with my threshold lines.

[image: sample1]
[image: sample2]

I have javascript map which gives me x values for each y values, but my threshold values sometimes does not exist in my map so i need to find closest value to draw that line.

[image: sample of mapContent]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: most left you have 2 crossings. you have to find the X belonging to an Y with binary search and path.getTotalLength() and path.getPointAtLength()

Comment: @rioV8 now i edited my question. Hope to made it clear and understandable

Comment: I understand the question. Your left most line is marking the local minimum not the crossing. You have a lot of points so just choose the point with the smallest delta-y

Comment: i made it with paint, i want a closest crossing x value.. i might have fault when drawing. but i want croessed lines.. thank you for your interest @rioV8, how will i measure all delta y's